# Why does my NixOS installation not have `~/.nix-profile/etc/profile.d/nix.sh`?

Tags: nix, nixos

A NixOS user, I am studying the [Nix Pills](https://nixos.org/guides/nix-pills/index.html). They frequently reference `~/.nix-profile/etc/profile.d/nix.sh` as a means of "entering the Nix environment". E.g. quoting from [chapter 5](https://nixos.org/guides/nix-pills/functions-and-imports.html):

> I remind you how to enter the Nix environment: source
> ~/.nix-profile/etc/profile.d/nix.sh

However, my NixOS machine does not even have a `~/.nix-profile/etc` directory, let alone a `~/.nix-profile/etc/profile.d/nix.sh` file. My questions:

1. Why might my machine not have `~/.nix-profile/etc`?
2. Is there an ordinary way to generate `~/.nix-profile/etc/profile.d/nix.sh`?
3. Is there straightforward alternative way to "enter the Nix environment" in NixOS?

Comment: `~/.nix-profile` is typically a symlink to `/nix/var/nix/profile/per-user/mherzl/profile`. That is, user-specific profiles are stored, like most Nix-related things, in the Nix store. The symlink just provides a simpler way for you to access it.

Comment: (I guess that comment answers Question 2; I'm not sure why it would not have been created in the first place, so no answer for Question 1.)

Comment: @chepner I see that my `~/.nix-profile` is indeed a symlink to `/nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/matthew/profile`, as you suggested. However, I do not see a `nix.sh` file there anywhere under `/nix/var/nix`.

Comment: Searching at the top i.e. from the `/nix` directory, I do see a few instances of `nix.sh`. E.g. `store/3xar9pka6mfq44d640znj6y0qd71x4a2-nix-2.3.10/etc/profile.d/nix.sh`. However, running `source store/3xar9pka6mfq44d640znj6y0qd71x4a2-nix-2.3.10/etc/profile.d/nix.sh` does not work to enter the `nix-repl`.

Comment: I don't have a ~/.nix-profile/etc directory either. Is this expected for non-NixOS machines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not yet have answers to (1) and (2), but do have an answer to (3). That is:

```
$ nix repl
```

works to enter the nix environment.

Answer (score 1):

According to the official documentation, profile could be automatically generated when you've switched to it by command:
$ nix-env --switch-profile /nix/var/nix/profiles/default

So, you should try this command and it should create missed files and directories.

Here is the text copied from official [doc](https://nixos.org/manual/nix/stable/package-management/profiles.html):

> You generally wouldn’t have /nix/var/nix/profiles/some-profile/bin in your PATH. Rather, there is a symlink ~/.nix-profile that points to your current profile. This means that you should put ~/.nix-profile/bin in your PATH (and indeed, that’s what the initialisation script /nix/etc/profile.d/nix.sh does). This makes it easier to switch to a different profile. You can do that using the command nix-env --switch-profile:

```
$ nix-env --switch-profile /nix/var/nix/profiles/my-profile

$ nix-env --switch-profile /nix/var/nix/profiles/default
```

> These commands switch to the my-profile and default profile, respectively. If the profile doesn’t exist, it will be created automatically. You should be careful about storing a profile in another location than the profiles directory, since otherwise it might not be used as a root of the garbage collector.